# SQL Server - move last two column values to rows with ranking

Tags: sql

This is the table I have, named as '#test'

```
create table #test 
(
population_id int,
web_id_parent int,
level_id_parent int,
web_id_child int,
level_id_child int
);

insert into #test (population_id, web_id_parent, level_id_parent, web_id_child, level_id_child) values ('840','10141','2','18399636','3');
insert into #test (population_id, web_id_parent, level_id_parent, web_id_child, level_id_child) values ('840','10141','2','3300681','3');
insert into #test (population_id, web_id_parent, level_id_parent, web_id_child, level_id_child) values ('840','10141','2','7112360','3');
insert into #test (population_id, web_id_parent, level_id_parent, web_id_child, level_id_child) values ('840','11937','2','11938','3');
insert into #test (population_id, web_id_parent, level_id_parent, web_id_child, level_id_child) values ('840','11937','2','26068','3');
```

```
|population_id|web_id_parent|level_id_parent|web_id_child|level_id_child|
|:------------|:-----------:|:-------------:|:----------:|-------------:|
|840          |10141        |2              |18399636    |3             |
|840          |10141        |2              |3300681     |3             |
|840          |10141        |2              |7112360     |3             |
|840          |11937        |2              |11938       |3             |
|840          |11937        |2              |26068       |3             |
```

The table I want in the final result is following :

```
|population_id|web_id       |level_id       |
|:------------|:-----------:|--------------:|
|840          |10141        |2              |
|840          |18399636     |3              |
|840          |3300681      |3              |
|840          |7112360      |3              |
|840          |11937        |2              |
|840          |11938        |3              |
|840          |26068        |3              |
```

The order is also ranked by level_id from smallest to largest for each web_id_parent.

I tried unpivot method, but didn't return the output I want.

```
select * from #test unpivot(web_id for level_id in ([web_id_parent],[web_id_child])) as #unpivot_table;
```

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
select DISTINCT t.* FROM(
SELECT population_id, web_id, level_id
FROM (SELECT * FROM #test)p
UNPIVOT(
web_id for level in (web_id_parent,web_id_child)
) pvt1

UNPIVOT(
level_id for web in (level_id_parent,level_id_child)
) pvt2 

where RIGHT(level,1) = RIGHT(web,1)
)t
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83e25842e198f03e2828642524258cc3)